# How to select text between tags in Adobe Brackets?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, adobe-brackets

How to select text between tags in Adobe Brackets like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> in Sublime Text?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this command is not done yet.   Check out https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Shortcuts for available commands & https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Working-with-Multiple-Selections for some selection commands.

You can also goto Help> Suggest a Feature and suggest this. It does sound like a nice feature, would be good to have.